# Filling the grid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

I wanna fill grid with a background worker but I don't know where I must add `DataGrid.DataSource=DataTable;` is there any simple example that explain how can I use background worker for filling `DataGrid`?

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    setgride();
}
private void setgride()
{
    string constring = "constring";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandText = " select * from Request";
    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt2);
    propdt2 = dt2;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted Event , handle this event and assign source property here.

Comment: thank u very much for reply.it is work.but can i show each part of data that load in data set. for example if i had 2000 record if loaded 100 record in dataset i show it and then add the other record i add them in grid. can i do it in progress changed? and how.thanks my frind